# How to explain this contradiction?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let ${\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, and $1\neq \tau \in Aut({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}})$ such that ${\tau}^2=1$. For every representation $\psi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ of finite group $G$ of dimension $n$, we could define a Hermitian scalar product $\langle x, y\rangle:=\sum_{g\in G}(\psi(g)x, \psi(g)y)$ on $n$-dimensional ${\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}$-vector space $V$, where $(x, y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i(y_i)^{\tau}$ is the standard Hermitian scalar product on $V$, and $x=(x_1,..., x_n), y=(y_1,..., y_n) \in V$.

Since the Hermitian scalar product $\langle , \rangle$ is $\psi(g)$-invariant for all $g \in G$, we have $\psi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is equivalent to a unitary representation $\Gamma: G \rightarrow GL(W)$, i.e $\Gamma(g)$ is a unitary matrix for all $g \in G$. On the other hand, we know that unitary matrices are diagonalizable over the algebraically closed fields. Therefore all the elements of $\psi(G)$ are diagonalizable over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}$.

This leads to a contradiction if we consider for example the identity map $i: GL_2({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}) \rightarrow GL_2({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}})$ as a representation of group $G=GL_2({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}})$, because there are elements in $GL_2({\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}})$, such as $
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\       0 & 1 \      \end{array} } \right]
$, which are not diagonalizable over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}$.

How can I explain this? Thank you in advance for any enlightening description.

Comment: I think you should really spell out this scalar product in your counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean for $\tau$ to be an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p^{2n}}}$?  Otherwise I don't know what $(y_i)^\tau$ means.

Comment: @EricWofsey no. for example you can define $\tau: x \mapsto x^{p^n}$. This is an automorphism of ${\mathbb{F}}_{p^{2n}}$ which fixes the elements of ${\mathbb{F}}_{p^{n}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you don't know your inner product is nondegenerate.  For instance, if $G$ has order divisible by $p$ and acts trivially on $V$, then $\langle x,y\rangle=|G|(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y\in V$.  In the ordinary characteristic $0$ case, this isn't an issue, because you can use the positivity properties of inner products (you know $(x,x)>0$ for all nonzero $x\in V$, and so $\langle x,x\rangle>0$ as well since a sum of positive reals is positive).  But in characteristic $p$ you don't have an order, and you in general have no way of guaranteeing that your inner product will be nondegenerate.

Comment: Aha! I didn't notice that. Thank you.